# Insert or delete a subtext in a text file

Tags: python, text-files

I want to save the data in a text file of my choice and be able to manage the data I need to add or remove a string anywhere in the text file (not just the beginning and end of the file). I can not keep all the data in the file as a string variable in the program because the size of the data stored in the file may be too large. I can not read the entire file, apply the changes, and rewrite the file, and I need the changes to be executed directly on the file.
The main problem is that the `open` function can only append a string to the end of the file (not anywhere), or change a number of text characters in the middle of the text (not add new characters), or keep the text of the file from beginning to anywhere in the file and delete the rest. (Not a range of characters in the middle of the text).
Python 3

Comment: Yup, no common file systems allow this.''I can not read the entire file, apply the changes, and rewrite the file' why not?

Comment: I mean, an obvious suggestion is to use an actual database instead of a flat text file, but I guess that's no on:(

Comment: Adding/removing suggests that the file needs to be searched anyway.  You don't need to load the whole file to do that, just read/write a smaller buffer or two to search/replace/delete into a temp file.

Comment: Because the file size may be too large and it is not possible to save the variable in RAM

Comment: You can do it with two buffers, sized to be larger than any insert/delete string, (you need two because the search string may span the buffer boundary).

Comment: In fact, I want to design something like a database to store data
The question is, how do databases add or remove data?

Answer (score 0):

You can explore file seek, you can move anywhere in the file using file.seek() with cursor position.
and move through the whole file. But you have to a pointer to move forward and backwards to mark your offsets.

Comment: Moving file.seek() does not help because appending data to a text file is only possible from the end of the file.